# Number of doublings in a bounded submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, martingales, upper-lower-bounds

Let $1\leq X_n \leq N$ be a submartingale with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geq 1}$, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}] \geq X_n$ and $N \geq 0$ is a scalar. Suppose $X_0 = 1$ and let $n_k$ denote the index at which the process doubles for the $k$-th time, i.e., $n_0 = 0$ and for $k \geq 1$,
$$
n_k = \min\{n > n_{k-1}: X_n > 2X_{n-1}\}.
$$
Let $\kappa_N$ be the set of all these indices until time $N$ and $K_N = |\kappa_N|$ be the total number of doublings until time $N$. Can we bound $\mathbb{E}[K_N]$?

**My Approach:** In the special case where $X_{n+1} \geq X_n$ monotonically, we claim that $K_N \leq 1 + \log N$. because otherwise,
$$
X_{n_{K_N}} = \prod_{2 \leq n \leq n_{K_T}}\frac{X_{n}}{X_{n-1}} \cdot X_1 \geq \prod_{n \in \kappa_N, \\n \neq 1}\frac{X_{n}}{X_{n-1}} > 2^{K_N-1} > N,
$$
which is a contradiction with $X_{n_{K_N}} \leq N$. Can we prove something similar in the more general case of submartingales?

**Edit:** Originally the question was with $0 \leq X_i \leq N$. But, now it is changed to $1 \leq X_i \leq N$ to avoid the counter example provided by @Peter Morfe.

Comment: Set $X_{0} = 0$ and $X_{i} = 2^{i} \delta$ with $\delta > 0$ so small that $\delta 2^{N} < N$.  The total number of doublings in $\{0,1,2,\dots,N\}$ is $N$.

Comment: @Peter: I see your intuition about this that the first random variable can be sufficiently small so that the number of doublings is arbitrarily large. So, change the question by having the constraint that all X_i are larger than 1.

Comment: If you have a *sub*martingale with values in $[1,M]$ and do $N$ steps, then $E[K_N]\le C\min(M,N)$ and you cannot do much better, so for your case $M=N$ nothing interesting can be said. On the other hand, for a *super*martingale, the estimate becomes $E[K_N]\le C\min(\log E(X_0),N)\le C\min(\log M,N)$, which is much better but which is not what you are interested in.

Comment: Could one argue, that the sequence $X_{n}(\omega)$ cannot double $N$ times on $n\in [1,N]$, because then it would be monotone, and we have a bound. If $N$ is large, it can also not double $N-1$ times, because there would exist some point $M$, for which the sequence is monotone before and after, so we can bound by $1 + \log (M) + 1 + \log (N-M) \leq 2 + \log (2N -1)$. Proceed like this until some amount of doublings $D$, for which this upper bound becomes larger than $D$?

Comment: The upper bound of my previous comment may not be right, but the point is we can put an upper bound on $\log ((N-M)M)$.

Comment: @fedja True, I had the same thought and felt that a bound would make more sense for supermartingales since then the doubling times would be rarer events.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon OK, let's see what the OP has to say :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explicit submartingale for which $E[K_N] \ge cN$ for a constant $c>0$. (We will not try to optimize this constant).

Suppose that $2^\ell-1 \le N <2^{\ell+1}-1$. Consider the Markov chain $\{X_t\}$ (a variant of the "greasy ladder") that from 1 jumps to 3, and for each $j \in [2,\ell-1]$ jumps from $2^j-1$  to either $1$ or $2^{j+1}-1$ with equal probability. The chain is started at $X_0=1$ and is absorbed at $2^\ell-1$.
This chain is indeed a submartingale.

Let $\tau$ be the first time $t$ when $X_t=2^\ell-1$. Then $$P(\tau \ge N/8)\ge (1-2^{2-\ell})^{N/8-1} \ge 1/e$$ so $E[\tau \wedge N] \ge \frac{N}{8e}$. Let $I_t=1$ if $X_t \ge X_{t-1}$ and $I_t=0$  otherwise. Then $S_T=\sum_{t=1}^T (I_t-1/2)$ is a submartingale, so $$0 \le E[S_{\tau \wedge N}] \le E[K_N]- E[\tau \wedge N]/2 \le
E[K_N]-\frac{N}{16e} \,.$$

Comment: Very interesting! +1. The first place I saw the greasy ladder was in your book (Markov Chains and Mixing Times). The setup there was that you could go up by $1$, or all the way back to $1$ with probability half each. So this is a very smart modification of the ladder, and I see why the construction works : you are forcing doublings to occur by ensuring it always occurs whenever one doesn't go back to $1$, and then forcing the chain to not regularly revisit $1$.